# Distribute tokens to multiple addresses from wallet

Tags: wallets, tokens

How can i Distribute tokens from my new wallet "not contract" once?

AND

How select who token to send it

Answer (score 2):

> How can i Distribute tokens from my new wallet "not contract"

You can't really separate the token from the contract - it's a common misunderstanding; [you might find one of my previous answers enlightening](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/how-to-monitor-token-flow-after-crowd-sale/26377#26377).

The act of distributing a token from an address in your wallet to potentially multiple other addresses will require you interacting with the token's contract to update the respective balances.

Assuming that the token implements the [ERC20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) standard then the easiest way to achieve this would be by calling the *transfer* function on the token contract:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);
```

If you already have the tokens balance against your address ("in your wallet"), and just want to write a quite script to send the tokens or achieve this through an Ethereum node's console then you can use [web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3-javascript-app-api) to interact with the token contract - and call the *transfer* function with the appropriate arguments.

There's a similar question about [distributing tokens to multiple addresses](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27778/distribute-token-to-multiple-address/27780#27780) that you might find useful if you are trying to distribute these tokens via a smart contract.

Comment: can u give code for send tokens with webjs 
am noob in solidity